# MapR volume audit

Tags: audit, mapr

I have a volume which is part of another volume.For example, I have directory '/' mounted as volume 'rootVol' and directory '/test'(which is part of /) as volume 'testVol'. I have enabled auditing for both the volumes and the underlying directories and files.The problem is when I try to create a folder inside '/test', it is audited as 'LOOKUP' action with status 2 instead of 'MKDIR'. But, folder gets created.

Is there some reason for this? Or, on any suggestions on how to correct it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the audit logs generated in all the nodes. Since the audit operation would be logged in which node the master container resides, you have to check the other node audit logs also to see the MKDIR operation.

Reason for LOOKUP getting audited is, for MKDIR operation to be done, a lookup will be done for the new directory name, if the file/directory is not available status 2 will be returned and then file/directory creation will happen.